# How to access custom classes in Interface Builder from a static library

Tags: xamarin.ios, interface-builder, static-libraries

Good day,

I have a static library (libGPUImage.a), it contains a class `GPUImageView`, i want to use `GPUImageView` in Interface Builder.

I tried to add the static library to the project in XCode. It does not show up in the custom class drop down list, and when i write it manually i get the error "**IPLab[7909:1507] Unknown class GPUImageView in Interface Builder file.**" when i build.

How do i introduce `GPUImageView` to Interface Builder if i have it in a static library?

By the way, i am using MonoTouch and am trying to bind the library.

Thank you.